# Win32 API hooking/Import address table

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, hook

Can anybody please read this and correct my mistakes/answer my questions?  This is my understanding so far:

The imports known at compile time, are loaded in memory when the executable is loaded in memory. Pointers to these functions are stored in the import address table, when a process wants to call a function it has to retrieve the pointer from the import address table (I understand the relation between the IAT, INT, H/N table etc.).

When a function is loaded at runtime with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress()` the dynamic linker retrieves a pointer; so e.g. when a process calls MessageBoxA then the operating system loader loads the DLL Kernel32 in memory and returns a pointer to this specific function. Is this part so far correct?

- As far as I know, the first library loaded by the operating system **by definition** is ntdll.dll and the second one is the more abstract wrapper Kernel32.dll. What I'm wondering.. when a process calls MessageBoxA or CreateFileA at runtime, the DLL does not need to be loaded in memory right? Because these functions are part of an already loaded library, namely Kernel32.
- Does the dynamic linker store the pointer to the dynamically loaded function in some sort of a cache or..? As far as I know, it does not update the import address table, so what happens when the process calls the function again, does it needs to call `GetProcAddress` again to resolve the virtual address or is there a more efficient way?
- When I want to hook the **dynamically** loaded functions, do I need to hook `GetProcAddress` at runtime and alter the return pointer with a jump instruction to my shim function (and store the original function pointer to call the original function/with the original parameters afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

> when a process wants to call a function it has to retrieve the pointer from the import address table

Retrieve sounds a bit cumbersome, but yes: Calls to imported functions are compiled into calls to the IAT where there's a JMP [Address] instruction, which gets patched up with the actual function address when the library is loaded.

> When a function is loaded at runtime with LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress() the dynamic linker retrieves a pointer; so e.g. when a process calls MessageBoxA then the operating system loader loads the DLL Kernel32 in memory and returns a pointer to this specific function.

`LoadLibrary` loads the dll into memory. `GetProcAddress` returns a pointer to a specific, exported function. Not a stub like above, but the address of the actual function within the module.

> when a process calls MessageBoxA or CreateFileA at runtime, the DLL does not need to be loaded in memory right?

`MessageBoxA` actually resides in user32.dll, but for CreateFileA you are correct, kernel32.dll is already loaded.

> Does the dynamic linker store the pointer to the dynamically loaded function in some sort of a cache or..?

The loaded module's address is recorded in a kernel object. As far as I am aware, the addresses of individual functions are not cached.

> As far as I know, it does not update the import addres table, so what happens when the process calls the function again, does it needs to call GetProcAddress again to resolve the virtual address or is there a more efficient way?

Normally you would store what `GetProcAddress` returns in a variable if you need to use it more than once.

> When I want to hook the dynamically loaded functions, do I need to hook GetProcAddress at runtime and alter the return pointer with a jump instruction to my hooked function (and store the original function pointer to call the original function/with the original parameters afterwards).

Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Regarding my last question (maybe I'm a little confused between this option and inline hooking), because in x86 we have to replace the first n (usually 5) bytes with a relative jmp to call the custom function; but how does this regard to altering the return pointer of the GetProcAddress call.

Comment: If you patched _all_ the exported functions of a module in the way that you suggest, you would not need to hook `GetProcAddress`. Conversely, if _all_ functions were loaded with `GetProcAddress`, and not via an import table entry, you would not need to do patching but could just return your custom function pointers to the caller from the `GetProcAddress` hook. Does that answer your concern?

Comment: Sir one more question; although I want to hook the Win32 API calls, I just want to monitor them, for a specific process. So process x called CreateFileA and CreateFileW for example (with a timestamp). Do I still need to inject a custom DLL? I know that there are tools like API monitor or process hacker that does this, but I want to write it myself. I can use Detours or Easyhook, but I'm curious if DLL injection is necessary. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if IAT hooking (with an injected dll) is the _only_ way to do it, but it is _a_ way - it's what I would do if I needed it.

Comment: Okay thank you, and my last question, I promise :) I read an article from mr. Chen about the IAT being not writable since a couple of years. Do you know more information about this? I looked on the internet quite a lot but nobody really mentions it, but there are recent tutorials that did in fact hook IAT, which implies that it is still possible. 

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221006-07/?p=107257

Comment: I haven't had to do this in a while, but I assume what that means is just that you have to call `VirtualProtectEx` to temporarily change the IAT's protection while modifying it. If you find otherwise and run into an issue that you can't work around, I suggest you post another question just with that.